# MS Graph - Get a DriveItem by Path return Internal Server Error

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

In recent days, Microsoft Graph started returning errors.

This is only happening in the SharePoint and not in OneDrive. And then only when used with use [pathToFile](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get): `/sites/{siteId}/drive/root:/{item-path}`.

Example request:

```
/v1.0/sites/<tenentName>.sharepoint.com,<siteId>/drive/root:/Demo-ALL/Files/file.xlsx:/
```

Returns:

```http
500 Internal Server Error

{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError",
        "message": "Unknown Error",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "64ed3a12-d0b0-4292-882f-75a541fbd7ba",
            "date": "2017-11-07T11:38:15"
        }
    }
}
```

This was working as recently as last week and I do not know who to turn to.

Email support does not work (dxipfb@microsoft.com)

Any ideas?

Comment: We are having a similar issue using Microsoft Graph SDK since last monday, please someone help!!